# Ruby create csv files in new subdirectory

Tags: ruby, csv, mkdir, fileutils

UPDATE BELOW

I have a Ruby script that is looping through some JSON and creating multiple .CSV files with the data. Currently it just creates those in the same folder as script/JSON. However, I want it to create the files in a newly created subdirectory that is timestamped.

I know I need `require 'fileutils.rb'` and I created `time = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%")` and `outdir = FileUtils.mkdir(time)`

I added these to my script and it successfully creates the directory but then breaks.

The end of the script that creates the files looks like this and I think the problem is the way I am going about moving into the directory/creating the files in the new dir:

```
...
    outdir = FileUtils.mkdir(time)
    FileUtils.cd(outdir) do #I think this is wrong
      filename = k+".csv"
      out = CSV.open(filename, "w")
      csv.each{|item| out << item}
      out.close()
    end
  }
```

---UPDATE---

It appears the problem is when I am designating the dir path and the CSV module. I am getting the error `Invalid argument - ["20130312113853"]/regions.csv (Errono::EINVAL)`
When I look at the CSV module docs I see you can declare a path for reading CSVs but nothing on creating/writing to them in another direcotry. This is the first time I have used this module. Does anyone know how to approach this?

I think I need to declare the dir path for csv before `csv = []`?

Fullscript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json' 
require 'csv'  
require 'fileutils.rb' 

file = "parse_me.json"

ff = JSON.parse(File.open(file).read)
time = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
outdir = FileUtils.mkdir(time)
begin
  ff.each{|k,h|
    csv = []
    csv << h[0].keys
    h.each{|arr|
      holder = []
      arr.each_value{|v|
        holder << v
      }
    csv << holder
    }
      out = CSV.open("#{outdir}/#{k}.csv", "w")
      csv.each{|item| out << item}
      out.close()
  }
end
```

Comment: why not just include dirname into csv open? `out = CSV.open("#{outdir}/#{k}.csv", "w")`

Comment: @YuriyGolobokov I made that edit but I think the issue is where I am declaring it. I updated the post with more info and the full script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `FileUtils.mkdir` returns an `Array` as you [can create one or more directories in a same time, it returns an `Array` of the directory created.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir).

If you simply work with `time` directly, your code should work

```
...
FileUtils.mkdir(time)
FileUtils.cd(time) do
  filename = k+".csv"
  out = CSV.open(filename, "w")
  csv.each{|item| out << item}
  out.close()
end
```

Comment: This is the closest I have gotten to making it work as it creates the directory and creates the first CSV but then gives the error `'mkdir': File Exists - 20130312131351 (Errno::EEXIST)`. It appears that it is trying to create the the same folder each time it creates a file?

Comment: @tehaaron Is your last code snippet the one you use? When do you create the directory: in the loop or out the loop? Do you get that error when you run again the script or during the script?

Comment: Use a block with `CSV.open` instead of discrete open and close. It's the Ruby way.

Comment: @toch oops I had the mkdir in the loop. I originally had it happen beforehand. Moved it back to where it was and it worked fine. Thanks!